# Прочесть строку задом наперед и разбить по 3 знака (PHP)

Tags: php, javascript

Добрый день. Есть вот такая задача. Имеется большой набор цен в БД. Они представлены в следующем виде: 3000000, 100000, 5000. Каждая цена это новая запись в БД.
Необходимо сделать представление цен в следующем виде: 3 000 000, 100 000, 3 000. 
Как я понимаю, необходимо прочесть число, допустим, 3000000 задом на перед и после каждых 3 знаков поставить пробел. Затем вывести это все в обычном порядке. Может кто-нибудь подсказать, как это можно сделать? Обращаю внимание, что работаем только через PHP и js.

Comment: Прочитайте http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo number_format($cena, 0, '.', ' ');
```